# How can I access actual output instead of location index when I call methods in another method in a python class

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods

```
def get_all_values(self):
    values_list = [self.get_input_cable, self.get_output_cable, self.get_color, self.get_price]
    return values_list
```

This is the output when I called out the methods into a list and printed it.

```
\[\<bound method Charger.get_input_cable of \<__main__.Charger object at 0x1030b4e10\>\>, \<bound method Charger.get_output_cable of \<__main__.Charger object at 0x1030b4e10\>\>, \<bound method Charger.get_color of \<__main__.Charger object at 0x1030b4e10\>\>, 600\]
```

I have tried the below code:

```
class Charger(object):
    def __init__(self, input_cable, output_cable, color=None):
        self.input_cable = input_cable
        self.output_cable = output_cable
        self.color = color
        self.price = 0
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "Input: " + str(self.input_cable) + "\nOutput: " + str(self.output_cable) + "\nColor: " + str(self.color)
    # Getters
    def get_input_cable(self):
        return self.input_cable
    def get_output_cable(self):
        return self.output_cable
    def get_color(self):
        return self.color
    def get_price(self):
        return self.price
    # Setters
    def set_input_cable(self, input_cable):
        self.input_cable = input_cable
    def set_output_cable(self, output_cable):
        self.output_cable = output_cable
    def set_color(self, color):
        self.color = color
    def set_price(self, price):
        self.price = price
    
    # Behaviours (Methods)
    def sale(self,discount=0):
        sale_price = self.price - self.price * discount/100
        return sale_price
    
    def get_all_values(self):
        values_list = [self.get_input_cable, self.get_output_cable, self.get_color, self.get_price]
        return values_list

    

C1 = Charger("C type", "B type", "Black")
C2 = Charger("USB", "C type", "White")
C1.set_price(600)
C2.set_price(1300)

print(C1.get_price())
print(C2.get_price())

print(C1.get_all_values())
```

Comment: You are not calling the methods - just add `()` pairs after specifying each method:`values_list = [self.get_input_cable(), self.get_output_cable(), self.get_color(), self.get_price()]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the actual output value of a method called within another method in a Python class, you can either store the output value in a variable within the method and return it, or you can directly return the output value from the method call in the return statement of the calling method.

For example, if you have a method method1 that calls another method method2, you can either do:

class MyClass:
def method1(self):
result = self.method2()
# do something with result
return result

```
def method2(self):
    # do some computation
    return output_value
```

or you can simply do:

class MyClass:
def method1(self):
result = self.method2()
# do something with result
return result

```
def method2(self):
    # do some computation
    return output_value
```

In both cases, output_value is the actual output of method2.

Comment: yo ushould point out where the error is in the question's code, besides explaining how to do it from zero with another class.